# In Lightswitch how do I make search box work in a child gridscreen that is on a List Detail Screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In a Desktop Client ListDetail screen the "Search" box at the top of the screen works great when I search the parent Entity.  When a try to search child Data Grid that is attached to the ListDetail Screen no records are returned no matter which property/field that may have data I want as criteria.  Is there a way to make the "Search" box usable? If not, why is it placed on the form by default? How do I remove it?  In the example below if I search "CCA Joe" no records are shown.[image]